# Playing mp4 and avi files in android

Tags: android, media

I have mp4 and avi, two types of files on sdcard. Should I need to give full name with extension in code to play this file?

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get  `IOException`.

You are setting the path in `setDataSource`.
For example,

You want to play `sdcard/yourMP4file.mp4`,if you are not giving full path,then it will take `sdcard/yourMP4file` as filepath.....

Actually `sdcard/yourMP4file` does not exists,what exists is `sdcard/yourMP4file.mp4`. So you will get `IOException`

Comment: But if i have the name of the file without extension what should i do to play it?

Comment: You should get its fullpath otherwise u can't play it...From where are u getting the filename???..I mean u should had added its extension while saving to database,or somewhere else where u save

Comment: i am getting the filename from a server .And the filename is not having the extension. Is there any way i could play it.

Comment: If the server created by you,the server should add extension with it...If server is not created by you,then you just try to append ".mp4" or ".avi" in the code,and try to play it..if still get exception,try other extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Without the extension, the file can not be found correctly. `SetDatasource` will throw out exception.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)

Comment: But if i have the name of the file without extension what should i do to play it?